# How does a predefined slot return a resolution?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I'm building a simple Guess Who skill game for Alexa. I have two intents right now: GenderIntent and HairColorIntent.

GenderIntent has a custom slot to handle gender and related synonyms such as mapping "boy" and "man" to "Male". This is working great. It returns a resolution within the slot. Exactly what I need.

HairColorIntent has a predefined Amazon slot, AMAZON.Color. This is not working great as it never returns a resolution regardless of the color supplied.

Here is my model for GenderIntent and HairColorIntent:

```
{
    "name": "GenderIntent",
    "samples": [
        "are you a {Gender}"
    ],
    "slots": [
        {
            "name": "Gender",
            "type": "GENDER_TYPES",
            "samples": []
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "HairColorIntent",
    "samples": [
        "is your hair {HairColor}",
        "do you have {HairColor} hair"
    ],
    "slots": [
        {
            "name": "HairColor",
            "type": "AMAZON.Color"
        }
    ]
}
```

GenderIntent returns the following slot WITH resolutions:

```
{
    "Gender": {
        "name": "Gender",
        "value": "male",
        "resolutions": {
            "resolutionsPerAuthority": [
                {
                    "authority": "amzn1.er-authority.echo-sdk.amzn1.ask.skill.2ed972f4-1c5a-4cc1-8fd7-3f440f5b8968.GENDER_TYPES",
                    "status": {
                        "code": "ER_SUCCESS_MATCH"
                    },
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "value": {
                                "name": "Male",
                                "id": "63889cfb9d3cbe05d1bd2be5cc9953fd"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
        "source": "USER"
    }
}
```

HairColorIntent returns the following WITHOUT resolutions:

```
{
    "HairColor": {
        "name": "HairColor",
        "value": "brown",
        "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
        "source": "USER"
    }
}
```

I'd like HairColorIntent's HairColor slot to return the resolution. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Resolution is only returned if you use synonyms in your slot type.

Not exactly sure how you handle it in your code, for example Node.js would be:
`handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.Gender.resolutions.resolutionPerAuthority[0].values[0].value.name`

If you do not use synonyms (for example for the `HairColor` slot), you can get the value simply by `handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.HairColor.value`

Working with predefined slot types this should work well with your code. If you want custom slot types to also return resolution whether you actually use synonyms or not, you can always just simply give the value as a synonym and it should return the full resolution tree.

Hope that answered your question.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm confused as to what the predefined slots are actually doing then. My assumption was that they were essentially handling the synonyms and matching accordingly. But are they just returning the input value from the user with no validation? Right now with the predefined slot if I say, "is your hair WALRUS" then my slot value `handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.HairColor.value` is WALRUS. I was hoping there would be some handling that WALRUS is actually not a valid color.

Comment: Looking into that exact slottype it does look like it's one of the more... interestingly coded ones. It recognizes a lot of colours, but at the expense of accepting lots of non-colours too. Usually these slottypes are better than that, I guess wanting to accept whatever name people give to colours made them code it liberally.
The only real solution I can see at the moment is to either validate in in code or write your own colour slottype while hoping amazon will produce a more sensible, "oldschool" colour slottype
I assume walrus is some very nice darkish brown with grey in it.

Comment: basically what predefined slots do is they have a list of valid input values (or a syntax for them (for example:`amazon.date`)) and they match user inputs to those, basically doing "validation" themselves and only allowing those inputs to be passed through the slot.
This is where `amazon.color` seems to have gone off the rails. You have your baseline colours, but then you start going a bit into the wild, walnut, graphite, navy all have colour meanings while not actually being colours. And that lack of well-defined border lets lots of undesirable words in as colours

Comment: Thanks for the replies and the clarification! We ended up going with a custom slottype and basically only accepting the colors (and their synonyms) we need to match with our guessing game. It seems to be working well.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad something worked out, sorry it's not the most ideal, sadly the limitations are annoying and hard to avoid.